# Why Skrollr won't allow me to scroll on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, skrollr

I'm having some trouble with Scrollr. Specifically, I'm unable to scroll at all on mobile browsers.

My site is here: http://tinyurl.com/qd9s94y

I've wrapped everything within a div with the ID of 'scrollr-body' as explained here: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#what-you-need-in-order-to-support-mobile-browsers

I've included this div just inside of the body tags, but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: While you can get this to work, I would recommend that you just remove the functionality all together on mobile.  Even if you get this to work on your specific phone, I have a feeling that the results will be all over the board for other phones.

Comment: @JonBlack Well I will be hiding the navigation menu on mobile, but I still want this functionality on desktop. Right now, the page is completely unusable, even with the navigation hidden.

Comment: I think I might be a bit confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. The site seems to work fine on my cellphone.  What is unusable exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct ID should be

```
<div id="skrollr-body"></div>
```

Comment: Hey no problem! Skrollr is a very cool JavaScript plugin, but it can be testy, good luck!